# Does Find My Friends require that Wi-Fi be on & that the app be running to get notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, find-my-friends

I'm not getting notifications from "Find My Friends."

1. Do I have to leave Find My Friends always open to get notifications?
2. Does my friend's phone have to have Find My Friends open to send
   notifications?
3. Do I have to have Wi-Fi on to get notifications?
4. Does my friend's phone have to have Wi-Fi on to send notifications?

Comment: here is a good description how it works https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201493 the key is to have the LOCATION ON

Comment: The biggest problem with Find My Friend notifications is that Find My Friend notifications often Just Don't Work for No Good Reason. I've set alerts to tell me when my wife gets home and had it go off as she pulling into the driveway or 30 minutes after she's come into the house, or not at all. It's just not reliable, IME.

Answer (score 1):

1. No it doesn't have to always be open.
2. No, same as 1.
3. No, cellular connection works too.
4. No, cellular connection works too.

Find my Friends would need permission from you to share your location as well as your friend. Once you two are sharing your location with each other, Find My Friends can send notifications that you have requested.

Comment: Do I absolutely have to share MY location in order for Find my Friend to send notifications from those who are sharing their location?